# Product of $(t_i - t_j)$ for $1 \leqslant j < i \leqslant n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, complex-numbers, determinant

So we're studying Linear Algebra and our teachers are doing a terrific job in making us memorize solutions. Got hard stuck on this question:

Let $t_1, t_2,...,t_n$ be complex numbers. Show that:

\begin{gather}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t_1 & t_1^2 & \cdots & t_1^{n-1}\\
1 & t_2 & t_2^2 & \cdots & t_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & t_n & t_n^2 & \cdots & t_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} 
 = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & t_1 & t_1^2 & \cdots & t_1^{n-1}\\
1 & t_2 & t_2^2 & \cdots & t_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & t_n & t_n^2 & \cdots & t_n^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
=\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (t_j - t_i)
\end{gather}
First thing is, I'm not even sure what this product notation exactly means.
I also should mention that we are yet to study eigenvalues and eigenvectors, so the solution shouldn't use them. I genuinely am not getting anywhere with this question, so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is known in the literature as a [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  If you only want a hint, then recall that many statements which involve $n$ can be approached with induction.

Comment: Presumably. You want $1\leq i<j\leq n,$ not $1<i\leq j<n,$ because the value is trivially zero if you allow $i=j.$

Comment: "*First thing is, I'm not even sure what this product notation exactly means*"  Expanded out you have $\prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (t_j-t_i) = (t_2-t_1)(t_3-t_1)(t_4-t_1)\cdots(t_n-t_1)(t_3-t_2)(t_4-t_2)\cdots (t_n-t_2)(t_4-t_3)(t_5-t_3)\cdots (t_n-t_{n-1})$.  That is to say, it is the product of all differences of terms $(t_j-t_i)$ satisfying $1\leq i<j\leq n$

Comment: Thank you so much Jmoravitz and Thomas Andrews! Yes this does answer my question.